# qTip issues with stling of tooltip in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, qtip, qtip2

I have implemented qTip jquery plugin and it works perfect on chrome and FF, but in IE 8/9/10/11 doesn't work as it should:
1) Doesn't wrap word but extend tooltip out of browser if text is too long.
2) Doesn't show me arrow in top right corner.
This is whioe my code:

```
.ui-tooltip-light{border:1px solid #666; background: #fff; margin-top:10px;font: 14px/1.4 arial,sans-serif;border: 1px solid #666;
padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
text-align: left;
word-wrap: break-word;
padding-bottom: 1em;}
.ui-tooltip-light:before, .ui-tooltip-light:after{
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;    
}
.ui-tooltip-light:before {
    top: -10px;
    right: -1px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #666;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
}

.ui-tooltip-light:after {
    top: -8px;
    right: 0px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;    
}
.qtip-content a{color: #666;text-decoration: underline;}
.qtip-content a:hover{color:#a90000;}
.ttip{cursor:pointer;}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
        $('.ttip').qtip({
            content: "my test",
            show: 'click',
            hide: 'click',
            position: {
                my: 'top right',
                at: 'bottom center'
            },
            style: { classes: 'ui-tooltip-light' }
        });
    });
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

Comment: I will give 100 points to help me with this. But I can set bounty tomorrow. Please for help IE is my nightmare :-/

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? 2.x doesn't support IE8 and code using jQuery should be browser-independent

Comment: Look in your css. `normal | break-word` afaik is not correct. Looks like you pasted in a little too much from a doc. if this is the case please delete the Q - a c/p error is not likely to be helpful for others :)

Comment: I updated to ie9 now I need to downgrade to ie8. Btw in ie 9 it works doesn't extend in one line.

Comment: @rlemon that was my c/p mistake sorry.